# How to create table from model in another file in Flask Python?

Tags: python, flask

So I want to create a database but I want to separate file for better visibility but I can't figure out how I can create table from other file.

Basically my database is created but table don't seem to work...

here my main.py file :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run()
```

and here is my model.py file :

```
from main import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
```

Comment: try importing all the models.

Comment: Where ? At the beginning of my main.py file ?

Answer (score 0):

You just simply need to import it from the file it is in. Assuming your `model.py` is in resides inside `app/models` like `app/models/model.py`, then you can simply do

```
from app.models.model import User
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run()
```

You can then continue working on the model as you would do when it's in the same file. I also notice you're importing `db` from `main.py`. It would result in a circular dependency and would refuse to work. Simply make a `__init__.py` file in the same directory as the User model, and then initialize the db inside that file like such:

```
from flask import current_app as app
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

After this import db from `__init__.py`, like so:

```
from . import db  # . here refers to the __init__.py file

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
```

Comment: I still get a `RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.` error. Even if I wrap the db declaration in a `with app.app_context():`